# How to select last duplicate object in array of objects in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

There is an array of duplicate objects(same id) from which last repeated object needs to be selected.
Input:

```
{ 
    "message": [
        { 
            "name": "Abc", 
            "address":"Mumbai",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Pqr", 
            "address":"Pune",
            "phone":"91-1234985438",
            "id":456
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Abc",
            "address":"Delhi",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "name": "Pqr",
      "address": "Pune",
      "phone": "91-1234985438",
      "id": 456
    },
    {
      "name": "Abc",
      "address": "Delhi",
      "phone": "91-1234567891",
      "id": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

In output, it should take the last repeated object values. I tried distinctBy function on id field but it picks random object from duplicates.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "message": payload.message groupBy ((item, index) -> item.id) 
        pluck ((value, key, index) -> value) 
            map ((item, index) -> item[sizeOf(item) - 1])
}
```

Input:

```
{ 
    "message": [
        { 
            "name": "Abc", 
            "address":"Mumbai",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Pqr", 
            "address":"Pune",
            "phone":"91-1234985438",
            "id":456
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Abc",
            "address":"Delhi",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "name": "Abc",
      "address": "Delhi",
      "phone": "91-1234567891",
      "id": 123
    },
    {
      "name": "Pqr",
      "address": "Pune",
      "phone": "91-1234985438",
      "id": 456
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @olamiral , it’s working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

`distinctBy` is not random--It will maintain the first instance and eliminate all subsequent entries that match your uniqueness criteria.

If you reverse the array first and then do a `distinctBy` on the `id` you will be dropping all but the last elements.

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = { 
    "message": [
        { 
            "name": "Abc", 
            "address":"Mumbai",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Pqr", 
            "address":"Pune",
            "phone":"91-1234985438",
            "id":456
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Abc",
            "address":"Delhi",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }
    ]
}

---
message: data.message[-1 to 0] distinctBy $.id
```

If the original ordering is important to you then reverse the array again.  The expression will look like this:

```
message: (data.message[-1 to 0] distinctBy $.id)[-1 to 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thies is another same Problem:

input:
[
[
117,
112,
112
],
[
112,
113,
112
],
[
114,
112,
112
]
]

DW:

flatten(flatten(payload map ((key, index) -> {
ids:key distinctBy $
})).ids) distinctBy $

output:
[
117,
112,
113,
114
]